# Should polling class be static

Tags: c#, class, static

I'm writing utitlity in C# to poll ftp site every 5 minutes and if there are any new file it should download it to local directory. But I'm not sure whether I should make this poller class static ? Does it really matter if I use static or non static class as poller in terms of performance or good programming practice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your polling class needs to store states like

1. When did it start polling
2. How many times it has polled so far
3. Did the poll ever fail in the past

etc etc... It should be a non static class.

If all it is doing is something on the lines of

```
Pollresult DoOnPoll( string ftpsitename)
```

it is better off as a static utility class.

Answer (score 2):

Good programming practice? Depends on the situation. From a performance standpoint, though, it doesn't matter in the least. The time it will take to create an instance of an object is negligible.

Without context, I would recommend making it static, though. If there are things specific to an instance, like counters... make it instance.